# How to use a PIR motion sensor to light up a 3.8 VDC bulb using battery and relay

Tags: batteries, relay, arduino-uno, pir

I would like to detect motion to turn off my 3.8 V, 0.3 A DC light bulb using a PIR motion sensor.

Recently I tried to connect it to a 5 V relay, Arduino Uno, and two 3.7 V Li-ion batteries, and the bulb seemed to burn out.

Any ideas on what should I do to my circuit, and what values of battery I need? Or should I put in a resistor instead?

I tried to modify the schematic with battery and DC light bulb referring to the schematic from [here](https://www.electronicshub.org/automatic-room-lights-using-arduino-pir-sensor/):

[image]

Comment: Did you apply 7.4V across the bulb?

Comment: Apparently yes, is that why my bulb burnt?

Comment: Most probably. Could you please furnish a schematic?

Comment: Do you have a 5V battery? Why do you need 2 x 3.7V batteries? Can you manually draw the schematic of what you wired and upload a photograph?

Comment: Thank you so much for the schematic. Sorry but does 5v battery exists? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Hi Aween, Why not a 5V DC power supply?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the schematic.

A 3.9Ω 1W voltage-dropping resistor is used in series with the 3.8V bulb.

[image]

Comment: For the relay, do we connect it to no or nc? Because I want to turn off the bulb when the pir detect the motion.

Comment: Hi Aween, 'NO' contact is shown. To turn off the bulb with the signal, you would need to wire the 'NC' contact.

Comment: Hi Aween, Is my answer acceptable to you?